# Is the ownership qualifier inferred in the latest Clang/LLVM?

Tags: objective-c, clang, llvm

So, by mistake, I discovered that this two, both compile just fine:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIButton* addButton;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect keyboardRect;
```

As you may know, the default ownership qualifier should be `strong`, and since `CGRect` can't have that qualifier, I'm guessing it gets inferred to `unsafe_unretained`. However, I found nothing about it in the Clang docs. Is this thing documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qualifiers `strong`, `weak` and `unsafe_unretained` apply only to objects managed by ARC (e.g. blocks, objects of type `id`, etc). There's no ownership qualifier at all for properties of type `CGRect`.

Here are the references in the Clang documentation:

[Retainable object pointers](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retainable-object-pointers)

[Ownership qualification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualification)

The section on ownership qualification applies only to retainable object pointer types.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you for taking the time to find it in the docs (I was looking for a wrong thing). You can however qualify a non object with `__unsafe_unretained`, which is the reason for which I didn't saw the elephant in the room. I'm guessing that's possible just because the qualifier does absolutely nothing. Is not desirable tho.

Comment: @ValentinRadu I guess that makes sense that you can use `unsafe_unretained` on anything, since it basically tells ARC not to do anything with the pointer. I agree that it's a little odd, and I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Yes, it sort of makes sense, but is totally redundant. It's funny, all my life was a lie regarding this matter:). I started declaring non objects with `assign` before ARC and then with `unsafe_unretained`. Never stopped to think about it! The things is, I saw this in a lot of pretty notorious code out there. Actually, right now I'm looking at it in AQGridView and iCarousel. I need to do a "What if I told you" meme :) Nice one, thanks again!